# Partial Regression Plots and Effect Displays

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization

I cannot grasp how to illustrate a multivariable general linear model. Suppose I have a multiple regression in which I predict blood pressure with age, sex, and %fat. Now,  suppose I would like to illustrate association of %fat (predictor of interest) with blood pressure. In my estimation, I would report the beta-coefficient, CI, and p-value. For added graphical display, this is where my confusion stems.

I think the following is considered a partial regression plot, correct me if I am wrong. First, construct the GLM such that it is `blood pressure ~ age + sex` and then I calculate the residuals. I can then plot these residuals on the y-axis and then %fat on the x-axis to show the independent association of blood pressure and %fat. On this graph, can I also show a Pearson/Spearman correlation coefficient as oppose to the beta-coefficient? Given there is an association in the GLM, I can also added a regression line I suppose. Would like any correction if I am wrong at any step.

Additionally, I am curious what this package even does: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/effects/vignettes/predictor-effects-gallery.pdf

In what ways is it similar or different than my approach for a GLM.

**EDIT**

[image]

The beta coefficients are being reported from a GLM with other covariates. Look at Panel D, it's reported "VO2max, adjusted for fat free mass and fat mass versus age". It seems that a model of `vo2max~fat free mass + fat mass` was used to generate residuals and this was plotted against age. The beta-coefficient being reported is from that GLM model. I'm trying to understand the best approach. Is this an acceptable approach, or using methods described by `visreg` or `effects`in R.

AND, lastly: If I were to report standardized beta coefficients, could I still deploy this approach? The Standardized beta coefficient would still reflect the slope of the regression line, correct?